# Godot KinematicBody2D Collision overlap

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

I am trying to create kinematicBody that can move through other collision boxes of certain instances. Then once the user pushes a certain input, I want to look at all collisions and handle them a certain way. I have already create everything to handle collisions when the player moves into them, but I want the player to be able to stand above the item, then check to see if moving Vector2(0,0) would collide with any objects on the floor.

Perhaps this is not the best approach, if there are better suggestions of how to handle a kinematicBody2D object colliding with other objects and being able to walk over them, I'd love to hear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for collision layers. [Here](http://kidscancode.org/blog/2018/02/godot3_kinematic2d/) is a short but very good explanation.

In your case you simply change the collision mask of your kinematic body depending on the button that is pressed in order to check whether or not your player collides with the object.

Comment: Almost! This really helps, the only issue is when I detect collisions using kinematicbody2D's built in move_and_slide() or move_and_collide() my character gets teleported to right outside the collision box, I am now wondering if there is a way to detect a collision without that move, I am also moving Vector2(0,0).

Comment: The standard behaviour of move_collide and move_slide() is to bounce of the collision object. Therefore you bounce "back" to the outside of the collision area. There are multiple ways of avoiding this effect but the best way depends on your actual needs. If you just want to collect coins or open an item, I would recommend to let the item check if it collides with the player, rather then the other way around. This way the physics process of the player behaves normally and the item can alter the player state or inventory or whatever you want.